# Screen moves up/down very fast

Tags: windows-10, laptop, graphics-card, hardware-failure, ubuntu-16.04

I have an HP Spectre X360 convertible model.  Now, frequently, the screen starts to move up/down very fast. Sometimes by increasing the brightness, the flickering/moving up/down goes. And sometimes, it doesn't. In case it doesn't, I restart the laptop and sometimes in one or more attempts, it start working fine. I uninstalled the intel UHD graphics card and re-installed but that didn't change anything.

I don't know if this is a Windows problem since I have dual-booted OS and the screen flickers even on the start page which displays the option to select the OS (Ubuntu and Windows 10). I was using this laptop for more than a year and didn't have any problem. Any idea why this happens since I am new to this? Is it a hardware or software issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Could be both hardware and software. When you install Linux alongside Windows, regardless of who was there first, some peripherals can start to behave strangely because either OS doesn't use them exactly the same way. One thing you can try, if your battery is removable, is to remove it entirely, and press the Power button for about 30 seconds, then let go, put the battery back into place and start your PC, preferably on Windows first. This resets some power management parameters in the motherboard.

Comment: @Didier I was using dual OS for more than a year now. It didn't flicker then. Do you think this can be because of dual OS? (just as a possibility?) Unfortunately, I can't remove the battery..

Comment: One or several updates on either Windows or Ubuntu could have triggered this. That it be cross-platform seems to indicate a hardware issue, but again, drivers in one OS can set different parameters in the periperal firmware, that the other OS driver will have to counteract to impose its own device management parameters. Unplug everything from your PC, power cord included, and keep the Power button down for a good 20 seconds, then let go, wait for 10 seconds or so, and fire it up normally. That shoud do it on an HP laptop.